# getting file list with exclude keyword in powershell

Tags: powershell

In getting file list, `Get-ChildItem's` `Exclude` parameter is not working. But when getting folder list, Exclude parameter is working.

Getting folder list works using Exclude parameter.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Website" -Directory -Exclude "foldername" | foreach ($_) {
    try
   {
       Write-Host $_.Name
   }
   catch
   {
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
        "NOT ABLE TO CLEAN... :" + $_.name
   }
}
```

Getting file list is not working using Exclude parameter.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Website" -File -Exclude "filename" | foreach ($_) {
   try
   {
       Write-Host $_.Name
   }
   catch
   {
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
        "NOT ABLE TO CLEAN... :" + $_.name
   }
}
```

Is it something wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as your question is concerned, if you include a wildcard`(*)` in the `-path` parameter in order to search for `files` then it most probably seems to work. Below works for me in case of files. Here  the wildcard character specifies the contents of the `C:\Website\`.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Website\*" -File -Exclude "filename" | foreach ($_) {
try
{
    Write-Host $_.Name
}
catch
{
     Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
     "NOT ABLE TO CLEAN... :" + $_.name
}
}
```

But the strange thing was the wildcard`(*)` doesn't work with the `-directory` parameter.